# Foremost custom file type not accepted by -t argument

Tags: linux, data-recovery, forensics

I'm trying to recover a deleted file on an ext3 file system using the foremost utility.  The file I want to recover is a `hpp` C++ source code file.  However, foremost does not automatically support the hpp file extension, so I have to add it to the config file.  So, following the instructions on the man page, I add the following line to the config file:

`hpp n 50000 include include ASCII`

Then I run foremost as follows:

`$foremost -v -T -t hpp -i /dev/md0 -o /home/recover/`

Instead of doing anything, it just displays the help message.  If I change the `hpp` to `htm` or `jpg`, it works.  So apparently foremost isn't accepting the custom file type I added into the config file.  But I've looked over this dozens of times now, and I can't see what I'm doing wrong.  I'm following the instructions exactly.  Why doesn't foremost recognize the new file type I added to the config file?

Answer (score 6):

I stumbled across the exact same issue and dug a little deeper into it by looking through the `foremost` sources.

It turns out custom types added using the configuration file cannot be selected with the `-t` option. Your files will be found if you define the `hpp` type in `/etc/foremost.conf` and use

```
foremost -v -T -c /etc/foremost.conf -i /dev/md0 -o /home/recover/
```

This will also recover files matching all builtin types which will probably mean **a lot** of files. To work around that, patch the sources to not include any of the builtin types when using `-t all` (equivalent to not using `-t` at all). In `state.c`, at the end of the `set_search_def` function, `init_all` is called if `strcmp(ft, "all") == 0`. Simply comment out the call to `init_all` and the builtin types will not be used anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Create a new .conf file and remove everything in it except the settings for the type you need. an example would be (foremost_pde.conf):

```
pde y   200000  #include    #include    ASCII
```

make sure you delete all tab or space characters at the start of the line or otherwise the line will not be recognised. Save and close the conf file at a user location (e.g. ~/Desktop). Now use:

```
foremost -v -T -c ~/Desktop/foremost_pde.conf -i /dev/md0 -o /home/recover/
```

Comment: foremost have a lot of builtin types that will be collected without `-t` or with `-t all`, no matter how empty you keep your config file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `-c config file` option?

Comment: Yes, I tried it with `-c /etc/foremost.conf`

Comment: What happen if you don't use -t option?

Comment: foremost -t all -i image.dd can you try this